# TFS 2010 Custom Work Item fields not showing in OLAP

Tags: tfs, olap

I've created a custom "Bug" work item template, but when I pull the OLAP cube in Excel, none of my new fields are in the PivotTable field list.  I've manually refreshed the cube, but they're still not showing up.  Thoughts?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

When you define the custom fields you have to mark them as reportable="dimension" or reportable="measure" if you want them to get pushed to the data warehouse/cube.

See this article for more details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194942(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194942%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dylan.  I did that when I create the fields, but it's not working...  They're all set to Dimension.

Comment: How did you manually refresh the cube?  The cube is built from the datawarehouse, so you have to first refresh the DW, then rebuild the cube.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  refreshed in the datawarehouse, then I rebuilt the cube in excel.  Yet, none my custom fields show in the pivotTable...

Comment: You did the correct actions to get the custom field in the warehouse/cube. Open a Microsoft Support ticket to solve the issue. Another option could be to file a connect bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio